# What's wrong with my Pine Script v5 'ta.highest' function using math.max and ta.barssince and how can I make it work?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to build a function ta.highest, based on a function ta.barssince using a math.max function, but it doesn't work, please help. При вызове функции plot(highp) я получаю ошибку Error on bar 0: недопустимое значение аргумента длины Nan в старшей функции. Он должен быть >0. Я хочу отобразить функцию highp = ta.highest(d, int(math.max(1, p))).

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, max_bars_back=1000)
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = int(ta.sma(k, periodD))
//plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
plot(31, '1', color.yellow)
a = 31

bool isCond11 = ta.crossover(d, a)
bool isCond21 = ta.crossunder(d, a) 
bool isCond1 = ta.cross(d, a)


p = ta.barssince(isCond1)
highp = ta.highest(d, int(math.max(1, p)))
plot(int(math.max(1, p)))
//plot(highp) ???????????????????????????
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not help us at all. What is it that is not working? What is happening at the moment? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: When calling the plot(highp) function, I get an error, Error  on bar 0: invalid value of the length argument Nan in the highest function. it must be >0. I want to render a function highp = ta.highest(d, int(math.max(1, p))).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error on bar 0: Invalid value of the length argument (NaN) in the
> "highest" function. It must be > 0.

On the first bar, your variable *p* is undefined. It has a value *na*.

By propagation, `int(math.max(1, p))` results in *na* too, which is why the error is thrown.

In this instance, you can use [nz()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_nz), which replaces *na* values with 0:

```
highp = ta.highest(d, int(math.max(1, nz(p))))
```

This is described in the User Manual, and you can read more about it [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#na-value).